# issues with Mojang api

Tags: javascript, api

when i go to the server status api (https://status.mojang.com/check) i get a vary simple response.

```
[
    {"minecraft.net":"green"},
    {"session.minecraft.net":"green"},
    {"account.mojang.com":"green"},
    {"authserver.mojang.com":"green"},
    {"sessionserver.mojang.com":"red"},
    {"api.mojang.com":"green"},
    {"textures.minecraft.net":"green"},
    {"mojang.com":"green"}
]
```

i wrote some simple js to communicate with this api

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.open('GET', 'https://status.mojang.com/check', true)
request.onload = function () {
    // Begin accessing JSON data here
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
    data.forEach((server) => {
        console.log(server);
    })
}
request.send()
```

this gives me an array and key/value pair.
as you can see in the api, one of the listings is account.mojang.com, so i edited the code to give me the status of this server

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.open('GET', 'https://status.mojang.com/check', true)
request.onload = function () {
    // Begin accessing JSON data here
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
    data.forEach((server) => {
        console.log(server.account.mojang.com);
    })
}
request.send()
```

this returns an error because the periods in the key are confusing the js. anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Object.keys and Object.values to get the variables you need.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.open('GET', 'https://status.mojang.com/check')
request.onload = function (){
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    console.log("KEY => " + Object.keys(data[0]));
    console.log("VALUES => " + Object.values(data[0]));
}
request.send();
```

Comment: What is the output you are looking for

Answer (score -1):

```
(data.find((server) => server['mojang.com']))
```

Comment: Though the code itself may be short & simple, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28350683) (Note that short, code-only answers often end up in the Low Quality Posts review queue, and risk deletion).